# Where can I find the power management settings?

Tags: power-management

How can I change the energy savings settings? I want the program to turn off the screen after three minutes and go on stand-by after 7 minutes. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The following answer is based on the assumption that values like five minutes or ten minutes will be suitable in-lieu-of your desired values of three or seven minutes. 
Actually, the values can not be set to something like three minutes or seven minutes as you desired.

In my honest opinion, such small difference in values should not be an issue under the scenario you described.

---

- Click on the wheel icon at top right of your screen. Select `System Settings` from the drop down menu that appears.

[image]

- A new window for System Settings will appear. Click on `Brightness and Lock`.

[image]

- The window changes as below. Select the appropriate time out value. Click on `All Settings` at top left.

[image]

- You get the original window. Click on `Power`.

[image]

- The window changes to  the tab for Power.

[image]

- Again the select the appropriate time out value. Click on the cross to close the window.